# Margin или Padding для отступов между блоками?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, margin, padding

Кто-то задаёт расстояние между этими блоками паддингами, а кто-то маржинами, что выбрать? Теоретически расстояние между блоками - margin, но некоторые делают это паддингами, почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это зависит от того, что вы хотите. Если вы хотите, чтобы блоки были на расстоянии друг от друга - margin, если вы хотите, чтобы границы блока прилегали друг к другу, но контент был на расстоянии - padding.

Взял картинку из инструментов разработчика в microsoft edge, наглядно показывает padding и margin. Border - это граница блока/элемента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Бывают ситуации, что margin просто не подходит. Например если вы двум блокам зададите margin, то расстояние между ними будет "пустым". Т.е. будет просвечивать фон родительского блока. Если же нужен "стык" между блоками, но контент должен быть на расстоянии, то выход - padding.

Конечно, если у вас не какая-то специфическая ситуация, то лучше использовать margin, поскольку он для этого и предназначен.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!